# how to have a select dropdown menu when editing or creating in jTable?

Tags: java, jquery, drop-down-menu, jtable

if you visit jtable.org and try to edit one of their records on the demo table you will notice a variety of field types. Theres checkbox, theres dropdown menu. However in all the demos and downloaded examples the edit/create option only has textfields which is fine for a name but I need to know how to make it show a dropdown of options. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

In fields just add options.

```
options: {'0': 'Enabled', '1': 'Disabled'}
```